# Custom Doctrine2 'datetime' type also used for 'date' comparisons?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.1.7 in a Symfony 2.0 environment. To handle date and times correctly, I'm using a custom 'datetime' type to save every date and time in UTC in the database. When I load them, everything is converted to the current timezone. This works perfectly and is configured like this (in my Symfony project's `config.yml`):

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    types:
      datetime:  Acme\DemoBundle\General\UTCDateTimeType
```

I have an entity called `Usage` with a date attribute, that has the date type. Somehow I failed to retrieve any usage information for a specific date, say 2013-02-18. I eventually turned on the MySQL query log and found that the following query was performed:

```
...
FROM account a0_
LEFT JOIN resource_usage r1_
  ON a0_.id = r1_.account_id AND (r1_.date = '2013-02-17 23:00:00')
WHERE...
```

So here's the funny part, I believe two things went wrong. It appears the custom `datetime` type conversion occured (I'm in GMT+1) AND the wrong date format string is used by Doctrine2. Does Doctrine2 somehow override regular date types when a custom datetime one is applied? Or am I doing something wrong?

(I'm using the `WITH` construct in my DQL, but it also occurs when I'm using the same comparison inside the `WHERE`.)

Comment: If you got a custom datetime format, you should eventually give it another name instead of overriding the builtin one.

Comment: @Ocramius see the Doctrine docs which advise a similar solution to the OP's original situation - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine 2 ORM automatically applies conversions required by your custom type also on parameters you bind to it.

In your case, any comparison applied with `datetime` will bind the result of `Acme\DemoBundle\General\UTCDateTimeType#convertToDatabaseValue($value, $platform)` to your query.

If you want to handle only one particular case with your custom `datetime` format, you should probably give it another name, such as `'utcdatetime'` and then use it only where strictly necessary. That way, comparisons against regular `datetime` fields will still preserve the original behavior.

You can also force the binding type by using the third parameter of [`Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery#setParameter()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L218) and enforce parameter conversion your way.

Comment: But the thing is, the `date` attribute in the `Usage` entity is of the `date` type. Which has nothing to do with my custom `datetime` type.

Comment: Nevertheless, forcing the type through `setParameter` works in the end. But I still believe the behavior I noticed should be considered a bug.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's because of https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/ParameterTypeInferer.php#L53-L55 (type is detected automatically). Anyway, name your custom type in another way to avoid problems in future.